# How to remove Search Web from UITextView menu

Tags: ios, swift

```
// Subclass UITextView to remove default context menu items like Learn and Share and keep Cut, Copy and Paste
class TextView : UITextView {
  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    let actions = [#selector(copy(_:)), #selector(cut(_:)), #selector(paste(_:))]
    return actions.contains(action)
  }
}
```

I've used the above code to remove excessive menu items and only keep cut/copy/paste but recently there's a new menu item called Search Web that searches the highlighted text in Safari/Google. Is there a way to disable that too?

Answer (score 3):

Remove it in `buildMenu(with builder:)`

```swift
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if builder.menu(for: .lookup) != nil {
        builder.remove(menu: .lookup)
    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```